# What is cosX-cosY when X and Y are uniform random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid uniform  $$X,Y \sim U[-\pi,\pi]$$

Consider the following $$ U = cos (X)$$ $$V=cos(Y)$$ What is the distribution of $$W=U-V$$

I know that $$f_{U}(u) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-u^2}}\hspace{1cm} -1 \leq u\leq 1$$ $$f_{V}(v) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-v^2}}\hspace{1cm} -1 \leq v\leq 1$$

So then should I be taking the convolution $$\int_{-1}^{1} f_{U}(w+v) f_{V}(v)dv $$ Is this the right way to go? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have a better luck going to the [Fourier transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of the densities (use [contour integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration)), multiplying them, then using the inverse Fourier transform to get the density of the difference (see [Characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29)).

Comment: I don't think there is a nice closed form of the Fourier of this type of densities.

Comment: Try to use contour integration.